# How to get text from browser that is hidden in the html using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

How to get text that one can visibly see when visiting the page, but is no where to be found in the html code?

Often times, I can just use driver.pagesource to get the text from the page, but I have a case where I can visibly see the text, but it's not anywhere in the html file when I download it.

Comment: what do you mean by hidden text from browser ?

Comment: you probably need a solution like phantomjs, as the text is most likely brought in via some js callback that selenium is not firing

Comment: @Begueradj - updated quesiton. Got it, are you suggesting that driver.pagesource will work to pull in text with phatomjs? Testing this now.